Last Scheduled File Not Loading into Redshift from AWS
Every day, I receive 4 files on AWS S3. While 3 files load successfully into Redshift, the last file data not store in the redshift, possibly due to a timezone issue. How can I fix this problem?
Dag
The cloud_redshift_sync task in an Airflow DAG is configured with specific memory, CPU resources, execution parameters (like run date and backfill options), and a 3-hour timeout, to execute the cloud_redshift_sync function.
aws file timezone
enter image description here
cloud_redshift_sync = abc(
    dag = dag,
    task_id = "cloud_redshift_sync",
    default_args = default_args,
    airf_pod_memory = '2G',
    airf_pod_cores = '1'
    exec_function = 'cloud_redshift_sync',
    exec_args = {'airflow_run_date': '{{ ds  }}',
                      'backfill':'{{ params.backfill }}',
                     'backfill_start':'{{ params.backfill_start }}',
                     'backfill_end':'{{ params.backfill_end }}'
                     },
    execution_timeout = timedelta(hours=3)
)

main.py
def get_file_from_s3(s3_client, raw_bucket, folder, ds, backfill, backfill_start, backfill_end):
        print("Inside get_file_from_s3 function")
        files = []
        backfill_start = datetime.strptime(backfill_start, "%Y-%m-%d").replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
        backfill_end = datetime.strptime(backfill_end, "%Y-%m-%d").replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
        objects=get_all_s3_objects(s3_client, Bucket=raw_bucket, Prefix=folder)
        if (backfill).lower() == "true":
                print(f"Backfill mode enabled from {str(backfill_start)} to {str(backfill_end)}")
                for obj in objects:
                    print(f"Checking object {obj['Key']} with LastModified {str(obj['LastModified'])}")
                    if obj['LastModified'] < backfill_end and obj['LastModified'] >= backfill_start:
                        print(f"Adding {obj['Key']} to files for backfill")
                        filename = obj['Key']
                        print(f"File added for backfill: {filename}")
                        files.append(filename)
                return files
        else:
            print(f"Single day mode enabled for {str(ds)}")
            for obj in objects:
                #if obj['LastModified'] < ds + timedelta(days=1) and obj['LastModified'] >= ds:
                filename = obj['Key']
                print(f"Adding {obj['Key']} to files for single day")
                files.append(filename)
            return files

def cloud_redshift_sync(airflow_run_date,backfill,backfill_start,backfill_end):
    print("Starting cloud_redshift_sync function")
    date_pattern = '%Y-%m-%d'
    randkey = random.getrandbits(32)

    date_airflow = (datetime.strptime(airflow_run_date, date_pattern).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')).strftime(date_pattern))
    print(f"Calculated Airflow date {str(date_airflow)}")
    if backfill.lower() == "true":
        prefix = f'{context}/{folder}'
    else:
         prefix = f'{context}/{folder}/{str(date_airflow)}'
    print(f"S3 prefix generated: {prefix}")

    ds = datetime.strptime(airflow_run_date, date_pattern).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))

    # Fetch S3 objects
    objects = get_file_from_s3(s3_client, RAW_BUCKET, prefix, ds, backfill, backfill_start, backfill_end)

    print(f"prefix: {prefix}")
    if not objects:
        print('No files for date in S3 bucket')
        return


Can you elaborate on what "doesn't load" means?

Doesn't load means not storing in the redshift

You already seem to be partitioning the files in the S3 bucket by date. What is the reason for checking if last time of modification of the object falls within that day? Are all the objects in the bucket location modified at -08:00 UTC or does the timezone vary?

So you don't get an error suggesting the load "failed", perhaps it worked but placed the file in the "wrong" location. Your hypothesis about time zone seems a good one to me. Perhaps logging where the files are attempting to write to might be a good next step.
